Navigating between tabs using button or hyperlink in streamlit
I am creating multiple disease prediction system with six tabs. I want to add a button or hyperlink navigate to another tabs in streamlit.

I want to navigate to diabete prediction tab when the user click on click here button or hyperlink.
I have tried
st.change_page("Diabetes Prediction")) 
st.button(page="Diabetes Prediction"))

but it doesn't work.
Is there any solution to navigate ?

You can use st.switch_page to change pages in Streamlit. This has been introduced in Streamlit 1.30.0.
├── main.py
└── pages
    ├── page1.py
    └── page2.py

In page1.py, you set:
import streamlit as st

st.header("A cat")
st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/cat.jpg", width=200)

if st.button("Go to Page 2"):
    st.switch_page("pages/page2.py")

In page2.py, you set:
import streamlit as st

st.header("A dog")
st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/dog.jpg", width=200)

if st.button("Go to Page 1"):
    st.switch_page("pages/page1.py")

This creates a button that goes straight to the other page.
On page1, before the click:

After the click:


What should I do I have written all streamlit related codes in one single python file ?
